# Best way to customize Kendo components Angular

Tags: css, angular, user-interface, sass, kendo-ui

What is the best way of stylizing kendo components such as grids, charts etc.  adhering to best practices.

The ways in which I've been styling them
1 : **Using ng deep , host** and this isn't the preferred way since these have been deprecated and it isn't a good      practice to use these.
2 : **Applying CSS globally** for example in a layout.css but the problem with this is when you want more and more stylized components your layout.css grows a lot and that isn't good either.
3 : **Grid Configuration Options** it affects the performance with complex configurations.

Comment: Applying css globally is fine, but you should split up the styling for the components. F.e. a separate css for buttons, input boxes, grid, etc and then import them in one central css. I used to do it this way, and I think it is completely manageable.

Comment: Yes but it also puts a lot of load on your global CSS by importing lot of styling.And I don't think that's good.

Comment: Since Angular packs everything together, this can't be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say the best way to style kendo components is by customizing themes. This way you can change styles without overwriting them. First of all, you should choose a base theme: default, bootstrap, material, or fluent. See more details here https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/styling/ .

Then you can customize the selected theme. Kendo team provides several options for that, see here https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/styling/custom-themes/ .

It's possible to change quite a lot in the existing theme, but if it's not enough you can create your own: https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/styling/custom-themes/#toc-customizing-the-source-code .

By the way, you can also try their theme builder app https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/styling/theme-builder/ .